# SQL сортировка если есть в другой таблице

Tags: mysql, sql

Доброе время суток, есть некая таблица product_category и есть таблица product_category_offer

Нужное мне значение из product_category я получаю запросом

```
SELECT c.category_id, FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_category pc WHERE d2c.category_id = '" . (int)$category_id. "'
```

Все работает хорошо, но в случае когда категорий несколько, мне необходимо делать ORDER BY (При наличии category_id в таблице product_category_offer ставить ее первой)

Как проверить есть ли значение category_id в таблице product_category_offer

Comment: left join этой таблицы. И колонка id из нее будет NULL если записи нет, или с значением - если есть. Но это если запись там только одна для данного category_id. А если их больше, то тогда видимо подзапрос делать. с получением количества или первой записи. Хотя можно и left join обойтись, если готовы выполнять group by. Не видя полной структуры таблиц и не зная какие данные там находятся однозначно сказать невозможно

Comment: category_id  присутствует в двух таблицах, никакие данные из product_category_offer я получать не хочу, только сортировка если присутствует category_id  в двух таблицах

Comment: Все равно left join быстрее, чем подзапрос, если его с существующими данными можно сделать, то лучше его и сделать и в order by тупо указать id из той таблицы

Comment: Но, при этом ведь без под запроса будут дублироваться записи так как category_id и там и там...

Comment: Вот поэтому я и говорю, что невозможно ответить на вопрос в котором эти тонкости взаимоотношения таблиц не указаны. Записи например не будут задваиваться если во второй таблице ноль или строго одна запись подходящая по условию. В вопросе этого не оговорено. Если записей больше - то тогда group by должен помочь свести их опять к одной. Но если хочется подсапросом, то например `order by (select count(*) from product_category_offer where ...) desc` конечно приведет к желаемому

Comment: Спасибо большое все получилось